# Co-op / internship visa to Canada

Tags: canada, internship, tunisian-citizens

I am Tunisian engineering student, studying in Tunisia and hold only the Tunisian nationality.

As part of my curriculum, I want to conduct an internship / co-p in Canada, that will last more than 4 months, but not longer than 6 months.

What type of visa should I apply for? Am I eligible for one?